# Invoking method/scope issue in js class closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a jQuery plugin, and using the anonymous closure pattern to wrap the works. Internally I define an object prototype with several methods. My previous practice was to define a closure-global var self and set `self = this` in the constructor. I could then invoke any method on the instance by invoking it on self. Works fine for one-off single instance plugins, but not in the case of suporting multiple instances of the same plugin in a single page. In that case I was running into state being overwritten, I think because I used this single reference to the class code in all places.

Fast forward, I am trying to follow an example I found by Alex Sexton https://alexsexton.com/blog/2010/02/using-inheritance-patterns-to-organize-large-jquery-applications/

His code shows a use of `$.data(this,'myPlugin',MyClassObj)` for caching an instance of the class on the parent element. I clearly don't understand how to reuse that cached object. QUESTION 1: how does one reload the specific instance? An example of doing so in a closure context would be great.

Furthermore, within my design I have a couple of keydown handlers which ought to invoke a common redisplay function when they are complete. However, `this` is tied to the target of the event, and I can't see how to invoke another method from within this function. As I said before I used to use a closure-global to access other methods, but that seems ill-advised for multiple instance plugins. QUESTION 2: How do I regain the closure scope `this` from within a function which has overridden the value of `this` ?

```
(function($){
    var MyClass = {
        init: function(opt,elem) {
            this.options = $.extend({},this.options,options);
            this.elem  = elem;
            this.$elem = $(elem);
            this._build();

            $('.selector',this.elem).on('keydown', this._move );

            // other setup things 
            return this;
        },
        _build: function() {
            // build out the html object
        },
        _move: function(e) {
            if(which == 38) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // move some things, store some state 
                // QUESTION 1: how should I store this state?
            }
                // QUESTION 2: how should I invoke the redisplay fn?
            this._redisplay();   // does not work: this == e.target
        },
        _redisplay: function() {
             console.log( 'redisplaying state data' );
                // QUESTION 3: how should I be retrieving this state ?
        }
    }; // end of MyClass

    // Start up the plugin
    $.fn.myClass = function(options) {
        if ( this.length ) {
            return this.each(function(){
                if ( ! $.data(this, 'myClass') ) {
                    $.data(this, 'myClass', Object.create(MyClass).init(options, this));
                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Any insights really appreciated.

Comment: For #2. The best way that you can store this is to create a pointer to this inside of the function.  At the top of the function what I usually do if I want to maintain scope is use `var context = this;`  Some alternatives to that are to look up the native function prototype methods [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: For your example, in the `init: function` do this. `var context = this;` at the first line and then inside your on click invocation do this: `this._move.bind(context)`. That will effectively store a pointer to your MyClass's this scope and then bind the move to the scope of MyClass. You can also call `context._move` as well which will call the correct move function. It is a matter of preference at this point. You can also effectively do `this._move.bind(this)` because when the function gets bound to the handler, this is still referencing MyClass.

Comment: Thanks. Your pointer to .bind was the key for that piece. In jQuery idiom one uses `$.proxy(method,this)`.

Comment: Yeah sure. I'm not really sure what you are asking for question number 1. Can you elaborate maybe a little bit? - Like what it is you are trying to do. I'm not sure what you mean by reloading a specific instance.

Comment: The widget I am writing is a time-selector: I want to be able to use it twice on a form. One for the start and one for the end values of a range of time. As it stands now the second instance clobbers the data from the first so they are always equal. This should be easy, I'm just not clear on where and how to use `$.data()`.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you have an error with how/where you are declaring the variables in your time-selector. Each time-selector should have its own instance of `data` that lives inside of it. It sounds to me like they are both sharing the data variable.  Can you show me how you are using it so that I can see where the error exists. I'm not too familiar with the `$.data` plugin you are using but I know JS. You may just want to use `this.data = 'some data';` during your init method. That way each plugin instance has its own data bound to it.

Comment: Are you using [this data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) ?

Comment: Maybe I understand now. You're data declaration will overwrite previous data if you are binding it to the element using the same key. You may want to use something like `$.data( div, "start-data", {....} )`, and then `$.data( div, "end-data", {....})` possibly. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the jQuery's data method.

Comment: I would like to see how you are using your plugin after it is created if I can.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with some more context. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4IorOMJbTD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94142/discussion-between-nf071590-and-rsadmin).